# Showing fields in view without declared in columns

Tags: python, openerp-7

I'm new in OpenERP. I have some problems.
In the model project.project I don't have any column named "name".But this model inherit a field from  'account.analytic.account' like this.

```
_inherits = {'account.analytic.account': "analytic_account_id"}
```

It's possible having a field in view without declared in columns? It's not a error?

```
<record id="edit_project" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">project.project.form</field>
        <field name="model">project.project</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Project">
                <group colspan="6" col="6">
                    <field name="name" string="Project Name" select="1"/>   
...
</record>
```

In the browser I can see a field name="name" and string="Project name". 
I also have a function in in columns like this.

```
columns{   'complete_name': fields.function(_complete_name, string="Project Name", type='char', size=250),}

def _complete_name(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
    res = {}
    for m in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        res[m.id] = (m.parent_id and (m.parent_id.name + '/') or '') + m.name
    return res
'complete_name': fields.function(_complete_name, string="Project Name", type='char',        size=250),
```

So my question is  which of these field is showing on the screen.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the project view you can see a field `name`. What comes after string, for example `string="Project name"` is the string that will be near the field. So, what we have after `name` is name of a column, and what we have after `string` is string visible next to the field.

Next time when You dont know which field is shown in the view, click your username in top-right corner -> about OpenERP and in the popup window click "activate developers mode". When its active you can place your mouse pointer over a field and it will show You what it is.